# Using Libertinus Math and XeTeX, binomial coefficients don't diplay correctly in inline mode

Tags: fonts, xetex, amsmath

I'm using Libertinus Math as my math font in XeTeX, and $\binom{n}{k}$ gives me a binomial coefficient in which the lower entry (k) sticks out below the parentheses. Display math works fine [ \binom{n}{k} ] looks perfect.

Switching to another font (eg, Tex Gyre Pagella Math) solves the problem, but I don't want Pagella, I want Libertinus.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I tried redefining \binom using the \genfrac command, but I got the same results:

```
\renewcommand{\binom}{\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{}} %This looks identical to standard \binom.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}


\begin{document}

This  $\binom{n}{k}$ looks goofy, while \[\binom{n}{k}\] looks perfect. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works well with LuaLaTeX

Comment: you could use $n \choose k$ as a workaround,  (the original looks better in luatex than xetex) but I'd need to trace what's happening. in recent years amsmath re-implements genfrac in xetex/luatex to work around missing parameters in opentype math, not sure if that implementation s wrong or it's a font issue I had some difficulty getting \binom to work at all.

Comment: Hmm, using LuaLaTex on my MWE I get errors thrown by fontenc and fontspec. First error is: Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \fontencoding \encodingdefault\selectfont   (I don't use LuaLaTeX nomally, I have no idea what is going wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

The brackets used by `\atopwithdelims` (which is the primitive used when binomical coefficients are printing) in text or display math mode is the result of decision of a font designer. The font designer of Libertine Math decides a smaller brackets here than somebody expects.

You can solve this problem when you use different TeX primitives than `\atopwithdelims`. It means:

```
\def\binom#1#2{\left(\!{#1\atop#2}\!\right)}

test: $\binom{n}{k}$ looks OK in Libertine Math.

\bye
```

Comment: Good answer. But I have finished my votes. Happy Easter. I delete my answer.

Comment: I have not forgotten ...but I am in delay :-(